# Continuous capture desktop loop with OpenCV

Tags: c#, opencv

i have the following that captured the desktop and convert the bitmap to a map for edge processing in OpenCVSharp:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                                   Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height,
                                   PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    var gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);

    gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
                                Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
                                0,
                                0,
                                Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size,
                                CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bmpScreenshot); 

    Mat src = BitmapConverter.ToMat(bitmap);
    Mat dst = new Mat();

    Cv2.Canny(src, dst, 0, 0);

    using (new Window("dst image", dst))
    {
        Cv2.WaitKey();
    }
}
```

what i am trying is to live capture the desktop continuously update the dst window

i have tried a while loop with a sleep but the dst windows ends up just grey and hangs

is there a more efficient way to capture and convert in opencvsharp?

i found a python example but uses numpy and imagegrab is something like this possible with c#?

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
import cv2

def screen_record(): 
while True:
    printscreen_pil =  ImageGrab.grab()
    printscreen_numpy =   np.array(printscreen_pil.getdata(),dtype='uint8')\
    .reshape((printscreen_pil.size[1],printscreen_pil.size[0],3)) 
    cv2.imshow('window',printscreen_numpy)
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

OK found a way to possible do this, however its eating memory ive tried src.dispose() but still rips through the memory?

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Mat src = BitmapConverter.ToMat(makeScreenshot());
            Cv2.ImShow("window", src);
            Cv2.WaitKey(5000);
        }            
    }

    public static Bitmap makeScreenshot()
    {
        Bitmap screenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        Graphics gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot);

        gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

        gfxScreenshot.Dispose();

        return screenshot;
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sry for my late answer but I just saw the question and solved it myself:

You have to run a WaitKey in your while loop, because else windows (or who ever does this :)) can't proccess the image so just add:

```
Cv2.WaitKey(milis)
```